# MVP way implemented RealmRecyclerViewAdapter failing to update after Realm is changed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, realm, mvp

got a problem with RealmRecyclerViewAdapter (https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters).
To make things more complicated I realized MVP approach for RecycleViewAdapter, it creates presenters for individual items.
The MvpRealmRecyclerAdapter looks like this:

```
    public abstract class MvpRealmRecyclerAdapter<M extends RealmObject, P extends ModelPresenter, VH extends MvpViewHolder<P>> extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<M, VH> {
        protected final Map<Object, P> presenters;

        public MvpRealmRecyclerAdapter(){
            super(new RealmList<M>(), true);
            presenters = new HashMap<>();
        }

        public MvpRealmRecyclerAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<M> data, boolean autoUpdate) {
            super(data, autoUpdate);
            presenters = new HashMap<>();
        }

        public MvpRealmRecyclerAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<M> data) {
            super(data, true);
            presenters = new HashMap<>();
        }

        @NonNull
        protected P getPresenter(@NonNull M model) {
            System.err.println("Getting presenter for item " + getModelId(model));
            return presenters.get(getModelId(model));
        }

        @NonNull
        protected abstract P createPresenter(@NonNull M model);

        @NonNull
        protected abstract long getModelId(@NonNull M model);

        @Override
        public void onViewRecycled(VH holder) {
            super.onViewRecycled(holder);

            holder.unbindPresenter();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFailedToRecycleView(VH holder) {
            // Sometimes, if animations are running on the itemView's children, the RecyclerView won't
            // be able to recycle the view. We should still unbind the presenter.
            holder.unbindPresenter();

            return super.onFailedToRecycleView(holder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) {
            holder.bindPresenter(getPresenter(getItem(position)));
        }
    }
```

The implementation of AttachmentAdapter looks like this:

```
    public class AttachmentAdapter extends MvpRealmRecyclerAdapter<Attachment, AttachmentPresenter, AttachmentHolderView> {
        private Context mContext;
        public boolean mReadOnly;
        private int limit;

        public void setLimit(int limit) {
            this.limit = limit;
        }

        public AttachmentAdapter(Context context, @NonNull OrderedRealmCollection<Attachment> attachments) {
            super(attachments, true);
            initialize(context, false);
        }

        public AttachmentAdapter(Context context, @NonNull OrderedRealmCollection<Attachment> attachments, boolean readonly) {
            super(attachments, true);
            initialize(context, readonly);
        }

        private void initialize(Context context, boolean readonly){
            setHasStableIds(true);
            mContext = context;
            mReadOnly = readonly;
        }

        @Override
        public AttachmentHolderView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            // Inflate the custom layout
            View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_attachment, parent, false);

            // Return a new holder instance
            return new AttachmentHolderView(contactView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(AttachmentHolderView holder, int position) {
            // Binding viewholder
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected AttachmentPresenter createPresenter(@NonNull Attachment model) {
            AttachmentPresenter presenter = new AttachmentPresenter();
            presenter.setModel(model);
            return presenter;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected long getModelId(@NonNull Attachment model) {
            return model.getId();
        }

        // Some more code
    }
```

When user presses the "Add attachment" item (Big + sign) I call this method from my adapter:

```
    private void getAttachmentImageFile(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        ((AppCompatActivity)mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, CreationActivity.REQUEST_IMAGE_SELECT);
        return;
    }

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(((AppCompatActivity)mContext),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            OpportunityCreationActivity.REQUEST_PERMISSION_IMAGE
    );

}
```

This method start CreationActivity in which this method gets called when the user has selected file to use as an attachment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_FILE_SELECTED:
            presenter.addAttachment(data.getData());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This activity has it's own presenter that adds the attachment, the presenter add attachment method is as follows:

```
@Override
public void addAttachment(Uri uri) {
    Realm realm =  Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    String type = GeneralUtils.getMimeType(context, uri);
    realm.executeTransaction(t -> {
        long id = getId();
        Attachment attachment = Attachment.create(realm, Parent.class, id);
        attachment.setAbsoluteFilePath(uri.toString());
        attachment.setContentType(type);
    });
    realm.close();
}
```

This method executes the transaction adding the attachment to realm. Realm recycle view listens to realm changes and should notify new changes, but instead I get this exception:

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{bcfb957 position=1 id=0, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5297)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5479)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3534)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3019)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                                                                       at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1306)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                       ....
```

As I understand, the problem could be in threading, that realm is changed from different thread than the recycle view is listening on, but probably I am wrong. I know this all seems pretty cryptic and complicated but the situation is what it is.

Comment: What is your Realm version? Also this has nothing to do with threading, it has something to do with not calling the right `notify__` method on a recyclerview, but Realm writes should automatically do that if you use `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`.

Comment: Consider using `executeTransactionAsync`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce this could be it! I'll try!

Comment: @Necroqubus did you manage to make it work?